# using join with list in controller laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

hi so im trying to create a dropdown that is based form a sql joined query so far here is what i have (got a help from fellow stackoverflow-ers)

```
$cats  = DB::table('nsa_subcategory')
     ->join('nsa_maincategory' , 'nsa_subcategory.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'nsa_maincategory.maincategoryid')
     ->lists(DB::raw('CONCAT(nsa_subcategory.subcategoryname , " | ", nsa_maincategory.maincategoryname)'),'nsa_subcategory.subcategoryid');
```

what im trying to do was join 2 tables display the subcategory and maic category but the value i would get is the subcategory id the code above produces this kind of error

[image]

any ideas what im doing wrong or any ideas on how to improve my code? thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the `DB::raw` in the `->lists`, put it in your select and give it a name as in the code below `category`, then you retrieve it using `->lists`

```
$cats  = DB::table('nsa_subcategory')
           ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(nsa_subcategory.subcategoryname , " | ", nsa_maincategory.maincategoryname) AS category'),'nsa_subcategory.subcategoryid')
           ->join('nsa_maincategory' , 'nsa_subcategory.maincategoryid' , '=' , 'nsa_maincategory.maincategoryid')
           ->lists(category, subcategoryid);
```

Comment: @BourneShady glad it helps :)